# TreeListView (ObjectListView) get parent node

Tags: c#

I was just wondering if there was a way to get the text of the parent node when I click one of the child nodes. It should be a very simple functionality but it doesn't seem to be build in.

```
string ParentNode;
string SelectedNode;
private void treeListView1_CellRightClick(object sender, CellRightClickEventArgs e)
{
    // ParentNode = (trying to get this values)
    SelectedNode = e.Item.Text;
}
```

Comment: What UI framework is this?

Comment: What class is the treelistview?

Comment: @EricJ. I am using the library from this http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Comment: @deramko the class is from this http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html, it is not the standard treelistview

Answer (score 0):

to get previous node value on any column:
`treeListView1.Items[treeListView1.GetItem(treeListView1.SelectedIndex - 1).Index].SubItems[0].ToString();`
Or
`olvColumn1.GetStringValue(treeListView1.GetModelObject(treeListView1.SelectedIndex - 1))`
to get previous node value on current column:
`treeListView1.GetItem(treeListView1.SelectedIndex - 1).Text`